# Handlebar issues with two modal and datatables of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am new to handlebar.js and I am trying to solve a problem. The problem is that when I am using handlebars to render the response coming from the server, it's not updating the table. There are three important points to consider:

1. I have used jQuery Datables
2. I have used two modals (the second modal opens on click of a button that is on the first modal)
3. It's updating the tables only if I put the script tags above the table tags but that is causing a problem when the second modal is opened as it falls underneath the first modal

Handlebar template code is below:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>WorkMode</th>
            <th>Edit</th>                                                                                         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
        <tbody> 
            {{#RESPONSE_CODE }}
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{this.exec_city}}</td> 
                    <td>{{this.exec_first_name}}</td> 
                    <td>{{this.exec_mobileno }}</td> 
                    <td>{{this.exec_id}}</td>
                </tr> 
            {{/RESPONSE_CODE}}   
        </tbody> 
    </script> 
</table>
```

```js
$('#example').DataTable();
var source = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);  
$('body').append(template(result.RESPONSE));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use Handlebars to populate the table. jQuery DataTables is capable of integrating with an AJAX data source. See https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: ya i knw that but i want to load the data faster that is why i opted for handlerbars ...when i try to remove Data Tables still i am suffering with same issue..